# how plugin works with inject and object instead of class in play 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I need to migrate the play mailer plugin for play 2.4.I checked some samples for play 2.4 and found that all the samples uses classes for plugin. I don't want to convert it to class. Is there any way for it to work with Object?

Sample

```
class MyComponent @Inject() (mailerClient: MailerClient) {
    def sendEmail {
       val email = Email(......)
       ......
       mailerClient.send(email)
    }
}
```

Original Code

```
object MailHandler{
  def sendEmail(to: String) = {
try {
  val email = play.api.libs.mailer.Email(...)
  MailerPlugin.send(email)
}catch{
  case ex:Exception=>PlayLogger.instance.error(ex.getMessage)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use an object instead of a class in order to make it a singleton.

There is a special annotation for singletons (-> `@Singleton`) which makes sure there is only one instance of your class created.

Although they still use an actual class instead of an object.

An example could look like this:

```
import javax.inject._

@Singleton
class MailerClient {
  def sendEmail(to: String) = {
    try {
      val email = play.api.libs.mailer.Email(...)
       MailerPlugin.send(email)
    }catch{
      case ex:Exception=>PlayLogger.instance.error(ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

Have a look at the documentation:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Singletons

Comment: I not only want to use singleton but also want to use the static class.Object is perfectly for that and there are many objects in my project. Do you mean I have to convert all Objects to Classes?

Comment: You don't have to convert every object to a class. Only the ones you want to inject as Singletons. You can also write a wrapper for each object, but it looks as if the Singleton-annotation is a better solution.

Comment: Is there a way to use the Inject and still use scala Object? I have many Objects which need to use Singletons. It would be my last resorts to change every such Object to Singleton scala class as there will be too many references to be updated

Comment: you can use a wrapper, but then you'd have to use a wrapper-class.