# Unspecified value parameters: dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

In the context of battling to define a simple plain SQL DAO using Play and Slick latest versions 2.4.x and 3.0.3 respectively. I have the following:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.lifted.TableQuery

import models.Tables._

class BaseDao @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  val fundQuery = TableQuery[Fund]
}

object BaseDao extends BaseDao { /// <<<<<<<<<< Error here 
  // empty
}
```

I get the error `Unspecified value parameters: dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider` on the line `object BaseDao ...` and can't find how to fix this as the syntax for this use-case is really new to me and there are no similar definitions in the examples etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is defined with a constructor parameter:

```
class BaseDao @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] { ... }
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, as the error suggests, you need to provide an instance of a `DatabaseConfigProvider` when building the object:

```
val myDatabaseConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider = ...

object BaseDao extends BaseDao(myDatabaseConfigProvider) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks but the DatabaseConfigProvider is injected via Play Slick so I need injection somewhere. Basically the real answer lies in the incomplete `= ... ` you provided.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Hmm, it seems that using `@Inject` with objects isn't (currently) viable - see the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198534/how-plugin-works-with-inject-and-object-instead-of-class-in-play-2-4), for example. The suggested work-around seems to be to use a class instead, annotated with `@Singleton`.

Comment: There is no need to create object BaseDao , rather you can make the class singleton and inject into the controller . Guice takes care of creating an instance of the class and injecting it during runtime.